# Angular - ng-repeat not working with search controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a search controller that I am using:

```
function searchRes($scope, $http, API, CarDetailService, $state){

  $scope.$watch('search', function() {
    fetch();
  });

  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageSize = 5;

  function fetch(){
    $http.get(API + "/search/" + $scope.search)
    .then(function(response){ 
      $scope.details = response.data;
    });
  }

  $scope.select = function(){
    this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);
  }

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails');
  };

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="searchRes" class="mainSearch">

  <div class="searchBar">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" onclick="select()" placeholder="Enter Search Term" autofocus />
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="res in details.Search">
    <div>{{ res['Display Name'] }}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have tried:

```
ng-repeat="res in details"
ng-repeat="res in response.data"
ng-repeat="res in data"
ng-repeat="res in response"
ng-repeat="res in response.data.Results"
ng-repeat="res in details.data.Results"
```

Here is an image of what the API returns (data.Results):

[image]

**EDIT** when I do a console.log(response); I can see all the JSON data being returned (data.Results)

I know I am obviously not calling the data properly but I don't know what else to try which i guess is why I am here.

Comment: `$scope.fetch = function()` ?

Comment: What is the structure of `response.data`? An Array? An Object? Please post.

Comment: data.Results. Its an object and inside that object is the array that I am trying to loop through. I have edited my question. Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to add it.

Comment: `ng-repeat="res in details.Results"` ?

Comment: @cventr damn, one minute too late.

Comment: Use {{res.displayname}}

Comment: @cventr Ya that worked. I knew it was something simple. I forgot about the Results being return from Search. Create an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ng-repeat="res in details.Results"`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. Thumbs up.